# настройка sftp сервера на linux(sftp)

Tags: linux, сервер, debian, администрирование, sftp

Делаю sftp-сервер на linux(Debian). Хочу сделать такие настройки: 1) Пользователь загружает файлы на сервер по протоколу sftp(а если быть честным - загружает видео-поток на сервер) в свой домашний каталог. 2) Пользователь не может ничего, кроме загрузки файлов на сервер(он не может удалять или изменять файлы). 3) Ограничение для домашнего каталога пользователя - 50МБ( то есть он не может суммарно загрузить файлы более 50МБ)

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Создаёшь ISO (например ext4) и монтируешь. http://www.linuxsnippets.net/snippet/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-linux-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-vsftd

Answer (score 1):

Квоты на домашние каталоги через штатный механизм квотирования (`apt-get install quota quotatool`) плюс маленький самописный скрипт например для `iwatch` (есть и другие реализации работы с inotify), который по закрытию файла в домашних каталогах пользователей смотрит, видеофайл это или нет. Если файл нужный — тут же уносит его оттуда куда требуется для дальнейшей обработки. Ну или не уносит, раз пользователь вообще не должен загружать суммарно более 50 мегабайт.